# Can you use "I digress" after you rant, even if it is an excess rant of the original topic?

Tags: american-english, slang

Can you use "I digress" after you rant, even if it is an excess rant of the original topic?

Example:

```
Person 1:
I got banned from league of legends
Person 2:
ok
Person 1:
Evan you're really making me angry. I hate you
Others: 
talking for a while
Person 1:
"I was getting tag teamed by a circle jerk duo who both lost lane by themselves
If I can't type back to those scum f*ck degenerates league can kindly screw off I digress
```

My friends and I are arguing if this is a valid use of "I digress" (excluding wrong grammar). Thank you.

Comment: You *can* add "I digress" after a rant, but I would not usually do it. If you *do* it, it would cause everyone to burst out laughing. The effect is one of a form of bathos - a figure of speech, invariably humorous, in which the tone of the speaker suddenly changes from serious to mundane. A rant is a serious complaint issued angrily - "I digress" is polite, self-deprecating, and formal.

Comment: It’s completely out of place in your example.

Comment: Some comedians are known for delivering humorous rants with some level of mock anger, and in that context "I digress" may fit, but it doesn't fit after a serious rant. In any case the way "digress" is included in your example feels like a typo given how it is just stuck on the end of the sentence with no punctuation.

Comment: Welcome. "I digress" is a standard laugh and applause line in this context as stated by others. If you give a rant you should stand by it and live with it since you will have to. Posting it here does little to lessen its presence on the internet. Stay off the keyboard when you're angry.